# Is it possible to use a wildcard in KVC?

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to use wildcard in KVC like this.

Is it possible?

Or Is there other ways to use a wildcard to indicate a member variable?

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *test1;
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *test2;
@end

@implementation MyClass{
    NSNumber * test1;
    NSNumber * test2;
}
@synthesize test1;
@synthesize test2;
@end
```

using wildcard

```
MyClass *testClass = [[[MyClass alloc] init] autorelease];
testClass.test1 = @50;

NSLog(@"test value : %@", [testClass valueForKey:@"*1"]);
```

For detail codes.

A real reason i wanted is to indicate a member variable of instance by value of integer or nsnumber type.
If possible, it is easier to set values and read values of any instance.

For example of property part copy.

```
MyClass *testClass = [[[MyClass alloc] init] autorelease];
testClass.year_1 = @2012;
testClass.quarter_2 = @3;
testClass.month_3 = @8;
testClass.day_4 = @20;
testClass.week_5 = @4;

// copy propertys to other instance.
// Normal way
MyClass *testClassCopy = [[[MyClass alloc] init] autorelease];
testClassCopy.year_1 = testClass.year_1;
testClassCopy.quarter_2 = testClass.quarter_2;
testClassCopy.month_3 = testClass.month_3;
testClassCopy.day_4 = testClass.day_4;

// copy propertys by using wildcard
for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
    NSString *indicate = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"*%@", [NSNumber numberWithInteger:j + 1]];
    NSNumber *sourceProperty = [testClass valueForKey:indicate];
    [testClassCopy setValue:sourceProperty forKey:indicate];
}
```

Comment: Not without a custom `-valueForUndefinedKey:` implementation it's not.

Comment: Also: would using a `*` as a wildcard return an array of results? If so, how would you attempt setting it. If you give us some implementation details, then maybe we can come up with a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though I couldn't find a way to support wildcards using the syntax you were attempting. I found this roundabout method using the Objective-C runtime!

First we get all of the properties of the class you'd like to use

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>

unsigned int outCount;
objc_property_t *properties = class_copyPropertyList([MyClass class], &outCount);
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:outCount];
for (int i = 0; i < outCount; i++)
{
    objc_property_t property = properties[i];
    const char *propName = property_getName(property);
    if(propName)
    {
        NSString *propertyName = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:propName];
        [array addObject:propertyName];
    }
}
free(properties);
```

---

Then filter out the ones you actually want

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF ENDSWITH '1'"];
[array filterUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

---

Then actually use them

```
for (NSString *key in array)
    NSLog(@"%@", [testClass valueForKey:key]);
```

Comment: Caveat: I tested this on my existing classes, not on your example class, but did attempt to fix. Watch out for any copy, edit errors.

Comment: Please consider that this only works for properties, not generally for KVC compliant accessors.

Comment: I'd like to present james a beer if in bar. :D

Comment: Also note that this will NOT work with subclassing, a -1 for that.

Answer (score 4):

I'll raise your wildcards by adding Regex, and by using categories:

To read about how regex works with this, please read the [NSRegularExpression Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Features:

- Uses regex, for matching of a wide variety of keys
- Uses a category that works on any instance
- Caches key lists per class
- Full KVC support (not just properties, but accessor methods & iVars too!)
- Integrates flawlessly with current KVC methods (only uses the regex if the key wasn't found, improving performance)
- Subclassing doesn't mess it up, like @JamesWebster's solution
- Doesn't needlessly pollute the list of keys with `NSObject`'s methods
- Returns a NSDictionary of matched keys & values

Cons:

- Uses regex, which is slower and more complex to understand
- Slow initial lookup for a class (must iterate through all methods & iVars)
- Automatically overwrites the `-valueForUndefinedKey:` method, so it's possible that this could break some existing code (move it to it's own method to fix).
- Currently doesn't support setting of values (by design, that's a whole other bag of cats).
- Can have duplicate keyPaths in the result (not the biggest of issues, but stems from the fact that KVC matching is complex, and I have to implement all of the rules)
- Uses `NSRegularExpression`, which is only available in iOS 4 and later (not the largest of issues).

Version History:

- 1.0: Initial Release

So, here is the code:

**NSObject+KVCRegex.h:**

```
//
//  NSObject+KVCRegex.h
//  TestProj
//
//  Created by Richard Ross on 8/20/12.
//  Copyright (c) 2012 Ultimate Computer Services, Inc. All rights reserved.
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface NSObject (KVCRegex)

// custom implemenation
-(id) valueForUndefinedKey:(NSString *)key;

@end
```

**NSObject+KVCRegex.m:**

```
//
//  NSObject+KVCRegex.m
//  TestProj
//
//  Created by Richard Ross on 8/20/12.
//  Copyright (c) 2012 Ultimate Computer Services, Inc. All rights reserved.
//

#import "NSObject+KVCRegex.h"
#import <objc/runtime.h>

@implementation NSObject (KVCRegex)

static NSSet *keyPathsForClass(Class cls)
{
    NSMutableSet *keys = [NSMutableSet set];

    do
    {
        if (cls == [NSObject class])
        {
            // nothing good can come from trying to use KVC on NSObject methods
            break;
        }

        unsigned count = 0;
        Method *methods = class_copyMethodList(cls, &count);

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            // make sure that the method returns a value
            const char *methodName = sel_getName(method_getName(methods[i]));

            char returnType[64];
            method_getReturnType(methods[i], returnType, 64);
            if (strcmp(returnType, "v") == 0)
                continue;

            // make sure that the method takes no args (except for self & _cmd)
            if (method_getNumberOfArguments(methods[i]) == 2)
            {
                // add a duplicate entry for ones matching 'is'
                if (strstr(methodName, "is") == methodName)
                {
                    char *newStr = strdup(methodName + 2);
                    newStr[0] = tolower(newStr[0]);

                    [keys addObject:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:newStr]];

                    free(newStr);
                }

                [keys addObject:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:methodName]];
            }
        }

        free(methods);

        // now copy iVars

        count = 0;
        Ivar *ivars = class_copyIvarList(cls, &count);
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            const char *ivarName = ivar_getName(ivars[i]);

            if (strstr(ivarName, "_") == ivarName)
                [keys addObject:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:ivarName + 1]]; // iVar name starting with _<key>

            [keys addObject:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:ivarName]];
        }

        free(ivars);
    } while ((cls = [cls superclass]));

    return [NSSet setWithSet:keys];
}

// returns a dictionary based on 'key' as a regex
-(id) valueForUndefinedKey:(NSString *)key
{
    // lookup for later use
    static NSMutableDictionary *keyClassPairs;
    if (!keyClassPairs)
        keyClassPairs = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

    if (!keyClassPairs[[self class]])
    {
        keyClassPairs[(id<NSCopying>)[self class]] = keyPathsForClass([self class]);
    }

    NSSet *keyPaths = keyClassPairs[[self class]];

    // assume 'key' is a regex
    NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:key options:0 error:nil];
    NSMutableArray *matches = [NSMutableArray array];

    for (NSString *keyPath in keyPaths)
    {
        NSRange matchRange = [regex rangeOfFirstMatchInString:keyPath options:0 range:(NSRange) { 0, keyPath.length }];

        if (matchRange.length == keyPath.length)
        {
            // we have a match
            [matches addObject:keyPath];
        }
    }

    if (matches.count)
        return [self dictionaryWithValuesForKeys:matches];
    else
        [NSException raise:NSUndefinedKeyException format:@"Could not find a key that matches the regex in %@", key];

    return nil;
}

@end
```

**Example:**

```
@interface MyObject : NSObject
{
@public
    int normalIvar;
    id _underscoreIvar;
}

@property id     someProp;
@property BOOL isProperty;
@property int  nativeProp;

-(void) notAKey;
-(id) aKey;

@end

@implementation MyObject

@synthesize someProp, isProperty, nativeProp;

-(void) notAKey
{
    NSLog(@"Not a key!");
}

-(id) aKey
{
    return @"Value";
}

@end

int main()
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        MyObject *obj = [MyObject new];

        obj.someProp = @"a property";
        obj.nativeProp = 15;
        obj.isProperty = YES;
        obj->normalIvar = 172;
        obj->_underscoreIvar = @"Ivar";

        NSString *regex = @"[a|s].*"; // match a key starting with 'a' or 's', then matching anything else after

        NSLog(@"%@", [obj valueForKey:regex]); // prints "{ aKey = 'Value', someProp = 'a property' }"

        regex = @"_.*"; // match a key starting with '_', and then match anything else after

        NSLog(@"%@", [obj valueForKey:regex]); // prints "{ _underscoreIvar = 'Ivar' }"

        regex = @".*"; // match any key declared for this object

        NSLog(@"%@", [obj valueForKey:regex]); // prints "{ "_underscoreIvar" = Ivar; aKey = Value; isProperty = 1; nativeProp = 15; normalIvar = 172; property = 1; someProp = "a property"; underscoreIvar = Ivar; }"

        regex = @"(?i)[A-J].*"; // match (case insensitive) a key starting with A - J

        NSLog(@"%@", [obj valueForKey:regex]); // prints "{ aKey = value; isProperty = 1; }"
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey @Richard J. Ross III so what's the license on this thing? it just says all rights reserved.. can i copy it into my app that will be published into the app store?

Comment: @abbood I'll look into it - theoretically it should be possible to get all the properties from CoreData, and add them to the list.

Comment: @abbood Unfortunately NSManagedObject defines it's own `-valueForUndefinedKey:`, and as such it makes it difficult, but not impossible (method swizzling could technically make this work), to have it respond to the regex. I don't currently have the free time to fully implement a solution, though.