# Using ObjC class extensions' vars in class category

Tags: objective-c, categories

I declare a class extension interface adding vars to it. Is it possible to access those vars in a category of that class?

Comment: If the category is declared in the same compilation unit as the extension, and the variable is `public`, accessing it should be possible, but I am not sure. Did you give it a try?

Comment: ...is "public" an ObjC keyword?

Comment: @user732274 the keyword `@public` is, but it's really just a compiler hint. Any object can get any instance variable from itself at any time, because objc is a purely dynamic language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure - any variable is accessible through the runtime, even if it isn't visible in the `@interface`:

**SomeClass.h**

```
@interface SomeClass : NSObject {
    int integerIvar;
}

// methods

@end
```

**SomeClass.m**

```
@interface SomeClass() {
   id idVar;
}

@end

@implementation SomeClass

// methods

@end
```

**SomeClass+Category.m**

```
@implementation SomeClass(Category)

-(void) doSomething {
    // notice that we use KVC here, instead of trying to get the ivar ourselves. 
    // This has the advantage of auto-boxing the result, at the cost of some performance.
    // If you'd like to be able to use regex for the query, you should check out this answer:
    // http://stackoverflow.com/a/12047015/427309  
    static NSString *varName = @"idVar"; // change this to the name of the variable you need

    id theIvar = [self valueForKey:varName]; 

    // if you want to set the ivar, then do this:
    [self setValue:theIvar forKey:varName];
}

@end
```

You can also use KVC to get iVars of classes in UIKit or similar, while being easier to use than pure runtime-hacking.

Comment: This is what I get: [<NSAlert 0x111ce5580> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key idVar.

Comment: @user732274 obviously you can only use this if you know that the class has a variable named `idVar`. In your case, replace that with the variable that you need.

Comment: @user732274 then you aren't operating on the correct object. There's no way you are adding an iVar to a NSAlert, unless you are using the raw runtime methods.

Comment: I added NSString *idVar in a NSAlert class extension: is this wrong?

Comment: @user732274 yes. Class extensions only work for classes that haven't yet been linked. Adding a variable to an already existing class won't do anything.